# Passing smart pointer to function through non smart pointer argument

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Consider the following function:

```
void example(void **ptr){
    std::cout << *ptr << "\n";                   // pointer value
    std::cout << ptr << "\n";                    // pointer address
    std::cout << **reinterpret_cast<int**>(ptr); // value
}
```

The function signature ***cannot be changed***.

Is the following code valid, or should I use raw pointers?

```
int main() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> x = std::make_unique<int>(20);
    std::cout << x.get() << "\n";                 // pointer value
    std::cout << &x << "\n";                      // pointer address
    example(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&x));
}
```

[Live sample](https://godbolt.org/z/d1YjWsfbj)

Comment: does `example` need to take ownership of the `unique_ptr`? If not then even without the `void**` complication it'd make sense to just pass it the raw pointer

Comment: @AlanBirtles it does not need to take ownership, it's just a matter of memory management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not valid and has undefined behaviour.
(If it appears to work, it's because your particular implementation happens to store the `unique_ptr`'s underlying pointer as its first member in this particular situation. It is still 100% pure crystal-clear undefined behaviour, though.)

If you can't change the function, you need to pass it something that actually is an `int**` - `&x` is a `std::unique_ptr<int>*`, and no amount of casting can make a valid `int**` from it.
(I have found that it's often a mistake to think of the smart "pointers" as pointers.)

The way to get a pointer to the underlying object in a smart "pointer" is through `get()`:

```
int* p = x.get();
```

and then you can pass a pointer to `p` (you still need to cast it, though):

```
example(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&p));
```

Comment: It's a reasonable point, my question stems from the fact that all operations I performed in the object so far, render the expected result, but since that is one of the *features* of UB, that lead me to ask the question. All the several compilers I tested it in seems to be able to perform the expected operations.

Comment: The first (and possibly only) member of a `unique_ptr` is probably just a pointer so casting it to `int**` might work but it's definitely undefined behaviour and you're just getting lucky/unlucky that it does

Answer (score 1):

Generally only `void *` have special rights and privileges when it comes to playing funny games with casting. However, given the situation that you have to work with:

```
example(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&x));
```

Note that you're passing `&x` and laundering it with `reinterpret_cast`. In `example()` you should do exactly the opposite:

```
void example(void **ptr)
{
    auto x_ptr = reinterpret_cast<std::unique_ptr<int> *>(ptr);
```

Now you have a `std::unique_ptr<int> *` to work with. You can proceed according to your original plans. If you wish, your next step can be:

```
auto &x=*xptr;
```

And this `x` is the same `x` as in your `main`, for all practical purposes (and it is).

Comment: It makes sense.

Comment: Whether it's correct or not depends on what the function actually expects its parameter to be.

Comment: It's the usual, treating the value, simple example: `**reinterpret_cast<int**>(ptr) = 30;`

Comment: If `example()` expects a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, then get the `int *` out of your `unique_ptr`, store it in a plain `int *`, then pass a pointer to ***that*** variable, casted to a `void **`. In order to get a useful answer on Stackoverflow, it is necessary to ask a useful question.

Comment: The example is a simplification, the function expects compatible user defined types and change their values, hence the example of an `int`, which is easy to understand, but ok, I get the message. I would just like to know if the contruct is UB or if it is valid.

Comment: No, it's not. There's nothing in the standard that guarantees defined behavior if a pointer to a `unique_ptr` is interpreted as a pointer to a pointer to a value. I outlined several approaches that are as much within the bounds of defined behavior as possible. I'm confident that one of them, either verbatim, as is, or with some minor adaptations, will work here.